# Change date format to be all the same

Tags: php, date

I have some date formats that are mixed, some are Aug-12 and others are 12-Aug... how can I make them all so they're d-M format? I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$birthday = $dataA[8];
if ($birthday == date('M-d', strtotime($birthday))) {
    $birthday = date("d-M", strtotime($birthday));
} else {
    $birthday = $dataA[8];
}
```

Comment: wrap birthday in `date(strtotime())`

Comment: What a problem with the code ? it seems to be working and you can even remove `else` block

Comment: @splash58 I'm still getting a mix of the dates in the output. Maybe a cache thing but I'm convinced that should work.

Comment: @Rob http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/03a04fdfa191a002c51c3cd04582d74c53d7a4cb

Comment: @splash58 Thanks, it's like it's not detecting that a date is in M-d format so it doesn't hit the if statement

Comment: Yes, so it will work if you have only these two format in a source.

Comment: @splash58 So when I put a hard coded date in as Aug-12 it switches it, yet if it's left to pull in the data it doesn't... maybe the hyphen is causing an issue???

Comment: May be, any space or dash instead of hyphen. I can only guess

Answer (score 0):

If you don't even need to test for a year/month combination but only need to detect a text pattern (3 latin letters, a dash, 1 or 2 arabic numbers), then use a regular expression, i.e.:

```
$sBirthday= $dataA[8];
if( preg_match( '#^([A-Z][a-z]{2})-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$#', $sBirthday, $aMatch ) {
  $sBirthday= $aMatch[2]. '-'. $aMatch[1];
}  // Otherwise you already have the correct format
```